# svn commit --username folder_name

Tags: svn

Is this string a valid svn set of commands?

```
svn commit --username name folder_name -m 'initial project version'
```

I need to commit the specified folder without storing the username and password at svn. Just do far I can't find useful information in the manual to decide am I right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering should be fine as you've written here (if it's not, you'll get an error message to tell you that you got it wrong, so just try it).

If you don't want the credentials cached, use the `--no-auth-cache` switch as documented in `svn help commit`.

You can't commit to the repository anonymously if the repository is requiring that you provide credentials.

Comment: thanks a lot! It was my trouble, b/c I'm afraid to do something wrong at the site I update))

Comment: I'll tell you what I tell every person I train on Subversion: As a user, there is nothing you can do that will break the repository. Your working copy? Yes, but we can delete & recreate that. Create a funky revision? Yes, but we can roll that back easily enough. But you will not break the repository itself, so just go ahead and do what you were going to do.

Comment: Generally what I am afraid is to make commit of folders that aren't mine that are controlled by other developers) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine according to this 'cheatsheet'

http://www.vidy.ch/sites/default/files/field_spectacle_creation_file/subversion-cheat-sheet-v1.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find a solution at book u gave, but thanks anyway.

Comment: It's in the upper right corner: "Commit Changes to Repository"